# Multiple server for one main site

Tags: nginx, multiserver

I have a website and yet I am using single server for but now I want to more servers for my website.

I want to ask that is there any way through which if I update may script it will get updated on all the servers.

Lets say I have three Nginx servers and I am using cloud flare for traffic distribution so if I want to update may script I upload it on one server and it automatically update on other two.

Is it possible if yes then how?

Comment: removing quotes tag not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You should looking for something like [puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software))